# how to list the files between time range in unix

Tags: unix

I want to list out all the files between time range of a particular date. For example on July 09,I have several files generated but wants to list the files between 1AM to 4AM only. How to do it ? Guys please suggest.

Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

this command will work for you

in my e.g. 20150707 -start date
           20150709-end date

but this will work for date not time

find . -type f -mmin -$(((`date +%s`-`date -d 20150707 +"%s"`)/60)) ! -mmin +$(((`date +%s`-`date -d 20150709 +"%s"`)/60))

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to filter the files as per the time range only . I want to put it in a script and which will run and collect all the files that are generated b/w 1am to 4am of that particular day.Should not be a manual  process :( If you have any idea,please paste here.